# Generating/plotting a log-normal survival function

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have an accelerated failure time model in SAS LIFEREG that I'd like to plot. Because SAS is to profoundly bad at graphing, I'd like to actually re-generate the data for the curves in R and plot them there. SAS puts out a scale (in the case of the exponential distribution fixed to 1), an intercept, and a regression coefficient for being in the exposed or unexposed population.

There's two curves, one for the exposed and one for the unexposed population. One of the models is an exponential distribution, and I've produced the data and graph like so:

```
intercept <- 5.00
effect<- -0.500
data<- data.frame(time=seq(0:180)-1)
data$s_unexposed <- apply(data,1,function(row) exp(-(exp(-intercept))*row[1]))
data$s_exposed <- apply(data,1,function(row) exp(-(exp(-(intercept+effect))*row[1])))

plot(data$time,data$s_unexposed, type="l", ylim=c(0,1) ,xaxt='n',
     xlab="Days since Infection", ylab="Percent Surviving", lwd=2)
axis(1, at=c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180))
lines(data$time,data$s_exposed, col="red",lwd=2)
legend("topright", c("ICU Patients", "Non-ICU Patients"), lwd=2, col=c("red","black") )
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Not the prettiest graph ever, but I don't really know my way around ggplot2 enough to spruce it up. But more importantly, I have a second set of data that comes from a Log Normal distribution, rather than an exponential, and my attempts to generate the data for that have failed utterly - the incorporation of the cdf for the normal distribution and the like puts it beyond my R skills.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction, using the same numbers, and a scale parameter of 1?

Comment: When you use ODS SAS generally provides very nice curves now.  Without using SAS Graph isn't there an option in SAS to plot survival curves?  It could be that there is a default graph that would look good.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is within the SO-CV overlap, but a closer fit for CV than SO. It is a programming question, but it needs some *statistical expertise* to answer, and thus belongs on CV as per CV's [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @MichaelChernick As far as I can tell, LIFEREG can produce a *hazard* plot and some diagnostic plots, but not a survival function. To be fair, most people are looking to LIFETEST to produce survival functions normally - but I'm not in this particular case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The survival function at time t for a log-normal model can be represented in R with `1 - plnorm()`, where `plnorm()` is the log-normal cumulative distribution function.  To illustrate, we'll first put your plot into a function for convenience:

```
## Function to plot aft data
plot.aft <- function(x, legend = c("ICU Patients", "Non-ICU Patients"),
    xlab = "Days since Infection", ylab="Percent Surviving", lwd = 2,
    col = c("red", "black"), at = c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180),
        ...)
{
    plot(x[, 1], x[, 2], type = "l", ylim = c(0, 1), xaxt = "n", 
            xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, col = col[2], lwd = 2, ...)
    axis(1, at = at)
    lines(x[, 1], x[, 3], col = col[1], lwd=2)
    legend("topright", legend = legend, lwd = lwd, col = col)
}
```

Next, we'll specify the coefficients, variables, and models, and then generate the survival probabilities for the exponential and log-normal models:

```
## Specify coefficients, variables, and linear models
beta0 <- 5.00
beta1 <- -0.500
icu <- c(0, 1)
t <- seq(0, 180)
linmod <- beta0 + (beta1 * icu)
names(linmod) <- c("unexposed", "exposed")

## Generate s(t) from exponential AFT model
s0.exp <- dexp(exp(-linmod["unexposed"]) * t)
s1.exp <- dexp(exp(-linmod["exposed"]) * t)

## Generate s(t) from lognormal AFT model
s0.lnorm <- 1 - plnorm(t, meanlog = linmod["unexposed"])
s1.lnorm <- 1 - plnorm(t, meanlog = linmod["exposed"])
```

Finally, we can plot the survival probabilities:

```
## Plot survival
plot.aft(data.frame(t, s0.exp, s1.exp), main = "Exponential model")
plot.aft(data.frame(t, s0.lnorm, s1.lnorm), main = "Log-normal model")
```

And the resulting figures:

[image: Exponential model]

[image: Log-normal model]

Note that

```
plnorm(t, meanlog = linmod["exposed"])
```

is the same as

```
pnorm((log(t) - linmod["exposed"]) / 1)
```

which is the Φ in the canonical equation for the log-normal survival function: S(t) = 1 − Φ((ln(t) − µ) / σ)

As I'm sure you know, there are a number of R packages that can handle accelerated failure time models with left, right, or interval censoring, as listed in the [survival task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html), in case you happen to develop a preference for R over SAS.

Comment: @jhetzel I have developed a preference for R over SAS, but I this is Phase 1 of a somewhat more complex project, and I know SAS better. Trying to minimize potential for mishaps with unknown methods and unknown code. Translating it all to R is...on the list.

Comment: This is very useful! Would you know how to plot the confidence interval as well?